# Проблема с группировкой строк по дате

Tags: mysql, join

Господа знающие, подскажите!

Clicks:

```
CREATE TABLE clicks
(
    click_id INT(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ref_id INT(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    time INT(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL
);
```

Orders:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
(
    order_id INT(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ref_id INT(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    value DECIMAL(12,5) DEFAULT '0.00000' NOT NULL,
    commission DECIMAL(12,5) DEFAULT '0.00000' NOT NULL,
    time INT(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL
);
```

Хочу получить такую выборку:

```
"день" 
"count(clicks.click_id)"  
"SUM(orders.value)" 
"SUM(orders.comissions"
```

Вот что уже есть, но выдает 1 дату:

```
select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
  DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME( c.time )) AS day,
  COUNT(DISTINCT c.click_id) as clicks,
  COUNT(DISTINCT o.order_id) as orders_count,
  SUM(DISTINCT o.value) as orders_total,
  SUM(DISTINCT o.comissions) as comissions_total
FROM clicks AS c
  LEFT JOIN orders AS o
    ON (o.ref_id = c.ref_id) AND
  (
      FROM_UNIXTIME(o.time) BETWEEN
      CONCAT(DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(c.time)),' 00:00:00') and CONCAT(DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(c.time)),' 23:59:59')
  )

WHERE c.ref_id = 1;
```

Comment: А что вы хотите получить то в итоге? Не совсем понятно. Дата заказа = дате клика? И второй вопрос: почему просто не сделать `DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(o.time)) = DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(c.time)`?

Comment: как я понял из статьи на стэке, в этом случае не будут работать индексы. Хочу получить в итоге что к примеру вчера было 50 кликов + сумма заказов 5000 + сумма комиссии 500. Позавчера - 40 кликов + сумма заказов 6000 + сумма комиссии 600. Сегодня - 10 кликов + сумма заказов 1000 + сумма комиссии 100

Answer (score 0):

У вас данные в clicks и orders между собой не связаны, поэтому их переклейка ведет к умножению записей (если 4 клика и 5 заказов - то записей 20). Считать при этом суммы совершенно невозможно. Вы делаете `sum(distinct value)`, но это неверно, это посчитает сумму уникальных значений, а что если есть два заказа с одинаковым value ...

Поэтому собираем по датам нужные нам значения отдельно по каждой таблице, после чего результаты объединяем.

```
 select C.dt, C.click_cnt, O.ord_val, O.ord_com
   from (
    select date(from_unixtime(time)) as dt, count(1) as click_cnt
      from clicks
     where ref_id=1
     group by date(from_unixtime(time))
   ) C
  left join (
    select date(from_unixtime(time)) as dt,
           sum(orders.value) ord_val, sum(orders.comission) ord_com
      from orders
     where ref_id=1
     group by date(from_unixtime(time))
  ) O
    on C.dt=O.dt
```